# TemplateHTMLRenderer redirects to profile

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to learn how to use django-rest-framework. I am following the tutorial plus browsing the API. What I am trying to do is to use TemplateHTMLRenderer to serve static HTML translated in various languages. Unfortunately I always get redirected either to a login page or a profile page.

For example a simple terms of service.

under the templates folder

.
├── base.html
├── el
│   └── TOS.html
└── en
    └── TOS.html

The view

```
# returns the Terms of Service. For now hard coded to return en
class TOSView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (TemplateHTMLRenderer,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request)
        return Response({}, template_name='TOS/en/TOS.html')
```

and the url

```
url(r'^site/tos/(?P<lang>[a-z]{2})/$', TOSView.as_view(), name='TOSView'),
```

when I hit the url I get

```
[voger]$ http http://127.0.0.1:8000/site/tos/en/HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 15 Sep 2015 20:32:34 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <strong>Menu:</strong>
      <ul>
    <li><a href="/accounts/login/">Sign In</a></li>
    <li><a href="/accounts/signup/">Sign Up</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also tried to subclass the TOSView from RetrieveAPIView but still the same.

I also tried a function based view

```
@api_view(('GET',))
@renderer_classes((TemplateHTMLRenderer,))
def tos_view(request, lang):
    return Response({}, template_name='TOS/en/TOS.html')
```

Still no joy.

I don't know if it is relevant but I also have installed django-allauth.

Comment: Do you have anything in your settings for REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES'] ?

Comment: No, I don't have anything in my settings about REST_FRAMEWORK. No configuration at all except that I added it in the INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Are you seeing the results of that print() in your view? If so, are you sure your template is laid out properly, e.g., correct block names?

Comment: Amen. There were two mistakes in my template. First it should extend "TOS/base.html" not "base.html" and second I forgot to surround it with blocks. Can you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that your template is set up properly, including putting everything in the right `{% block %}` tags. It looks like your base template may be being output with no content in the blocks currently.